# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended while using pivot

Tags: oracle

when i am using the following query i get ORA-00933 error

```
SELECT * FROM sales PIVOT (sum(quantity) FOR color IN ('WHITE','DARK'));
```

Here my table description is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE SALES(
ITEM_NAME CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
COLOR CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
CLOTHES_SIZE CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
QUANTITY INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

and the test data is:

```
SKIRT DARK SMALL 2
SKIRT DARK MEDIUM 5
SKIRT DARK LARGE 1
SKIRT PASTEL SMALL 11
SKIRT PASTEL MEDIUM 9
SKIRT PASTEL LARGE 15
SKIRT WHITE SMALL 2
SKIRT WHITE MEDIUM 5
SKIRT WHITE LARGE 3
DRESS DARK SMALL 2
DRESS DARK MEDIUM 6
DRESS DARK LARGE 12
DRESS PASTEL SMALL 4
DRESS PASTEL MEDIUM 3
DRESS PASTEL LARGE 3
DRESS WHITE SMALL 2
DRESS WHITE MEDIUM 3
DRESS WHITE LARGE 0
SHIRTS DARK SMALL 2
SHIRTS DARK MEDIUM 6
SHIRTS DARK LARGE 6
SHIRTS PASTEL SMALL 4
SHIRTS PASTEL MEDIUM 1
SHIRTS PASTEL LARGE 2
SHIRTS WHITE SMALL 17
SHIRTS WHITE MEDIUM 1 
SHIRTS WHITE LARGE 10
PANTS DARK SMALL 14
PANTS DARK MEDIUM 6
PANTS DARK LARGE 0
PANTS PASTEL SMALL 1
PANTS PASTEL MEDIUM 0
PANTS PASTEL LARGE 1
PANTS WHITE SMALL 3
PANTS WHITE MEDIUM 0
PANTS WHITE LARGE 2
```

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The PIVOT operator was introduced in Oracle 11gR1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16579/whatsnew.htm#CJAICGHE). Your query works fine in that version or later. In earlier versions you will get that error:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM sales PIVOT (sum(quantity) FOR color IN ('WHITE','DARK'));
SELECT * FROM sales PIVOT (sum(quantity) FOR color IN ('WHITE','DARK'))
                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

So you don't appear to be using a version that supports the operator. In earlier versions you can perform the same task manually with aggregates and case statements:

```
select item_name, clothes_size,
  sum(case when color = 'WHITE' then quantity end) as white,
  sum(case when color = 'DARK' then quantity end) as dark
from sales
group by item_name, clothes_size
order by item_name, clothes_size;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use a subquery with pivot, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM (
     select * from sales
)
PIVOT
(
     sum(quantity)
     FOR color IN ('WHITE','DARK')
);
```

Sources:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#CHDCEJJE

Comment: The OP's query works as it is in 11gR2 because it's using `select *` anyway; but if it was selecting a subset of the columns then it would have to have a subquery. (And it should really be specifying columns; using `select *` isn't a good idea anyway). But, it's probably better to be consistent and always use a subquery anyway. That isn't causing the error though.